# Roman to Integer, return -1 if the input roman numeral is invalid? (Non-regex check)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this code here that returns the matching integer to the input Roman Numeral, and uses regex to check for validity of the input, if it's an invalid Roman Numeral like "VVIV" or "IIII", returns -1.

```
def ValidationOfRomanNumerals(string):
        import re
        boolean = bool(re.search(r"^M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$",string))
        return boolean
 

def romanToInt(s):
    roman = {"I" : 1, "V" : 5, "X" : 10, "L" : 50, "C" : 100, "D" : 500, "M" : 1000 }
    
    res = 0

    if not ValidationOfRomanNumerals(s):
        return -1
   
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i + 1 < len(s) and roman[s[i]] < roman[s[i + 1]]:
            res -= roman[s[i]]
        else:
            res += roman[s[i]]
    return res
```

My question is, is there a way to check for invalid Roman and returns -1 without using regex? Like a algorithmic way?

Comment: @OldBill wouldn't it be IV instead?

Comment: No IIII is not valid

Comment: @OldBill interesting.  I always thought the rules for roman numerals were to pick the subtractive form for 4s and 9s.  Went to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) and it had this to say: "There has never been an official or universally accepted standard for Roman numerals" and "there is a tradition favouring representation of "4" as "IIII" on Roman numeral clocks".

Comment: @OldBill 4 is IV not IIII, VVIV is XIV

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a regex to check you can use a simple if condition to check if it's valid or not.
Like this:

```
if s[i] not in roman or i + 1 < len(s) and s[i+1] not in roman:
        return -1
```

It will return `-1` if the character is not among of roman keys defined above.

Complete Code:

```
def romanToInt(s):
roman = {"I": 1, "V": 5, "X": 10, "L": 50, "C": 100, "D": 500, "M": 1000}

res = 0

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] not in roman or i + 1 < len(s) and s[i+1] not in roman:
        return -1
    
    if i + 1 < len(s) and roman[s[i]] < roman[s[i + 1]]:
        res -= roman[s[i]]
    else:
        res += roman[s[i]]
return res
```

Comment: This doesn't work, VVIV still returns 14 not -1, invalid Roman doesn't mean characters not in the roman map, but means the Roman letter order is wrong

Comment: yeah, you are right it will only validate characters. If you want to validate correct roman numerals it would be very tricky.